# Nodejs MySQL datetime formatting

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

So I have a bit of a weird issue. As far as I know, node-mysql should format datetime to javascript date objects. However, it's not.

This is the column:
mysql> select order_time from jobs;

```
+---------------------+
| order_time          |
+---------------------+
| 2016-05-20 16:18:35 |
| 2016-05-20 16:24:47 |
```

The returned value looks like this:

```
2016-05-20T14:18:35.000Z
```

But it should look like this:

```
Fri May 20 2016 14:18:35 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

Any ideas on why it gets misformatted?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else struggling with this:

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1423

Basically date objects are changed in node v6+, and will always display as an isoString.